# Regex with optional capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I know there are other questions with the same title but I couldn't find an answer within them.

I have a string that could be `/action` or `/action{key:value}`
I'm trying to get `action`, `key` and `value` in variables.

I've tried several regexps that are variations of this one:
`/^\/(.*?)(\{(.*)\:(.*)\})?/`

[`/^\/(.*?)\{(.*)\:(.*)\}/`](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=107265)
 matches `/action{key:value}` but not `/action`

[`/^\/(.*)(\{(.*)\:(.*)\})?/`](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=107266) (declaring the capture group as optional) matches `/action` but not `/action{key:value}` (it captures everything)

So if I declare the first group as lazy :

[`/^\/(.*?)(\{(.*)\:(.*)\})?/`](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=107267) it doesn't match anything anymore.

I know I'm close to the solution but I'm sure misunderstanding something basic :)

Comment: @SebastianProske Well, second example captures everything in the first capture group. Meaning `/action{key:value}` is captured as a whole and not in separate groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the whole `{...}` part in an optional non-capturing group, while keeping the first group lazy:

```
^\/(.*?)(?:{(.*)\:(.*)})?$
        ^^^             ^
```

https://regex101.com/r/S4DAy3/1

Or use a negative character set, excluding `{`s:

```
^\/([^{]+)(?:{(.*)\:(.*)})?$
```

Comment: Great, didn't even think of putting capturing groups in a non capturing group!  
Do you know why I have to put the $ at the end? Why does it need to know the string ends with this capture group? (I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me).

Comment: Your question indicated that the whole string is what needs to be matched, thus `^` and `$`. If you want to match inside a larger string, then don't use the anchors, and use the negative character set to exclude both `{` and `/`s: `[^/{]`

Comment: Like MrVoodoo, I didn't think of putting a capture group in a non capture group either. Most other answers to questions like these only suggest using a non capture group which makes the enclosing expression optional and that never answered the question of capturing an optional part of a string if it is present.